# Can I tap fewer than 7 creatures with Lullmage Mentor?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With [Lullmage Mentor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLullmage%20Mentor%5d)'s ability:

> Tap seven untapped Merfolk you control: Counter target spell.

Can I attempt to tap less than 7 creatures with his second ability? I know it would not activate his second ability, but can I at least make the attempt to tap 7?

Basically can I intentionally fail to tap 7 creatures and those creatures still get tapped?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No you can't.  due to rule 117.3

> 117.3. A player can’t pay a cost unless he or she has the necessary
>   resources to pay it fully. For example, a player with only 1 life can’t pay a cost of 2 life, and a permanent that’s already tapped can’t be tapped to pay a cost. See rule 202, “Mana Cost and Color,” and rule 602, “Activating Activated Abilities”

---

the text: `"tap 7 merfolk"` is before the `:`, and therefore it's a cost.  You can't pay or attempt to pay that cost unless you are able to pay it fully.